# Bash PowerShell window will not close

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, powershell

I have been having an issue lately where a script will freeze on the Creators Update PowerShell window running Ubuntu 16.04 bash, and I cannot terminate the script using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> -<kbd>c</kbd>  or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> -<kbd>d</kbd>  and I cannot close the window.  If I try to open another PowerShell window I cannot get into bash.

How do I fix this issue?  I cannot seem to find PowerShell anywhere in the Task Manager, either.

Comment: bash and powershell are two different things. Please clarify ...

Comment: if you type "bash" in powershell it launches the linux subsystem for windows

Comment: @JakeOrben - We are more than aware of that.

Comment: I do not exactly know how to be more explicit then.

Comment: If you're having trouble figuring out what a process is in windows, you could use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx). Click the crosshairs and drag it to the window of the program and it will highlight the parent process for you. That being said, I think the process you need to kill in task manager would be `bash.exe`